# Is that true that each ideal $I \subset k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ of finite $k$-codimension contains all monomials of sufficiently high degree?

Tags: polynomials, ideals

Let $k$ be a field, and $I$ be an ideal in the $k$-algebra $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ of all polynomials of $n$ variables.
Suppose that $I$ has finite codimension over $k$, i.e.
$$
\dim_{k} k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/I < \infty.
$$
Is that true that

> (1) there exists $m$ such that $I$ contains all monomials $x_1^{a_1}\cdots x_n^{a_n}$ of degree $a_1+\cdots+a_n \geq m$?

This is equivalent to the statement that

> (2) there exists $m$ such that $x_i^{m} \in I$ for each $i=1,\ldots,n$.

Note that a priori these conditions do not imply that $I$ is generated by monomials.

I am especially interesting in the case when $f\in \mathbb{R}[x,y]$ is a real polynomials in two variables.
I would be grateful for any comments, suggestions or references.

Comment: It doesn't even seem to be true if $n=1$. The ideal $(x-1)$ in $k[x]$ has codimension one and contains no power of $x$.

Comment: On the other hand, if your ideal is homogeneous then it's obviously true.

Comment: @DaveBenson Thank you very much for the reply. 
Yes, (x-1) in k[x] is a counterexample, so probably I need to reformulate the question, because I also allowed to make changes of coordinates.
But how to see that this is true for homogeneous ideals?
For example (x-y) in k[x,y] still does not contain monomials, though it is now of infinite codimension

Comment: Since the codimension is finite, for each $i$ there is some linear relation modulo $I$ between the powers of $x_i$. Since the powers all have different degrees, this implies that some power of $x_i$ is in $I$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am very greateful for the help.
Actually in my case I have an ideal generated by two homogeneous polynomials $f,g\in \mathbb{R}[x,y]$.
Very wonderful, your arguments mean that if $I \subset k[x,y]$ is a homogeneous ideal, and $\sum_{i=1}^{k} c_i x^i \in I$, then $x^i \in I$ for all $i$ with $c_i\not=0$.
In particular, if $I$ is of codimension, say $5$, and it does not contain $1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4$, then $x^5$ must belong to $I$.